# Get two value and pass to next page at same time

Tags: asp-classic

How do i put this two together , could i get sessionid and objectid and the same time?

```
<% mLink = "rec_edit.asp?ObjectID=" & mObjectID %>   

<% mLink = "rec_edit.asp?sessionid=" & request("sessionid") %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
<% mLink = "rec_edit.asp?ObjectID=" & mObjectID & "&sessionid=" & Session.SessionID %>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to pass the SessionID in the query string though, as it's stored in 'Session.SessionID' already...

Comment: I want to do it at a same time  when user click the button , anyway , thx for your help rich ^^